# Rails + JQuery: Can not update span content with Ajax query

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some trouble using an Ajax query in a Rails + JQuery ecosystem.
What I want to do is to update the content of a span with the answer to an AJAX request when I click on a link.

Here is the interesting part of my view:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label "Avatar (laissez vide pour utiliser votre gravatar)" %><br />
<span id="avatar">
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
</span><br />   
<%= link_to "Editer votre gravatar", "http://www.gravatar.com/emails", :target => :_blank %><br />
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<%= link_to "Supprimer avatar", "/users/new/delete_avatar?id=#{@user.login}", :remote => true, :confirm => "Etes-vous sur?" %>
```

My goal is to update the span with the ID "avatar" when when click on the last link.
Here is the code that receive the request:

```
  def delete_avatar
        user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
        user.avatar.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path @user }
            format.js
        end
  end
```

And here is the delete_avatar.rb.js file, called by the respond_to:

```
$("#avatar").html("<%= gravatar_for @user %>");
```

Now, when I click on the link and use the query analysis tool of Firebug, what I get is a GET request, with an status code 304 or 200 depending on if the content is the same as before or not, with the following content:

```
$("#avatar").html("<img alt="foobar" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/f3ada405ce890b6f8204094deb12d8a8?size=150&amp;default=http%3A%2F%2Fskullslab.elhu.me%2Fimages%2Fskl_avatar.png" />");
```

This seems to be what I'm expecting, but I don't know why, the content of the page isn't modified.

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now, and I'm quite sure the answer is really straightforward... but I'll be grateful for any kind of help, thanks!

PS: JQuery is correctly loaded into my app, since I'm able to update the content of a span when clicking a link when I'm not trying to use AJAX.

Comment: What happens if you rename your file to `delete_avatar.js.erb`?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong file name. The file is indeed named delete_avatar.js.erb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to javascript escape your garatar_for in rails code, like this:

```
$("#avatar").html("<%= escape_javascript gravatar_for @user %>");
```

The problem is that you are having qoutes (") in your string, and that makes the javascript illegal. (unless you use ' for the jquery html method instead of ", but thats just a bad workaround)

Also, it may be a good idea to watch this little exelent screencast from RailsCasts on rails and jQuery. He mentions this in that episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Hopes this helps you out

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much! I was stuck on this, and I had really no idea why.
I'm going to watch this screencast right now, it'll probably save me loads of time on stupid mistakes like that next time.

Once again, thank you very much!